# How do i add Point coordinate as item to listView1?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

This is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < CloudEnteringAlert.PointsInt.Count; i++)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(CloudEnteringAlert.PointsInt[i]);
}
```

PointsInt is a List
For example in index 0 i see: {X = 120 , Y = 130}

Before the listView i used listBox and it was working no problems i could add it.
But when i changed it to listView im getting error:

Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Point' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem'

What i should see in the listView in the end is for example in index 0: X = 128 , Y = 130

Comment: You could set the actual ListViewItem to the text of each value, and then add the PointsInt object to the ListViewItem tag, for retrieval later on, if you needed to retrieve it later on, of course :)

Comment: Correction: When i used listBox i saw in index 0 for example just : 120 , 130 and that's how it should be with the listView but im getting error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
listView1.Items.Add(CloudEnteringAlert.PointsInt[i].ToString());
```

**Edit:**
As @LokiSinclair also suggested, if you have access to `.X` and `.Y` members, then you can do:

```
listView1.Items.Add(CloudEnteringAlert.PointsInt[i].X.ToString() + ", " + CloudEnteringAlert.PointsInt[i].Y.ToString());
```

Comment: gnarlybracket i tried your answer and i did it also string t = CloudEnteringAlert.PointsInt[i].ToString(); and just added the variable t. The problem in my solution and in your solution that its adding: {X = 120 , Y = 130} and i want it to add only: 120 , 130

Comment: @user3163653 are there any `.X` or `.Y` options available for `CloudEnteringAlert.PointsInt[i]`?

Comment: If it inherits from Point, then you'll have access to the .X and .Y members (as stated by @user3163653). In which case, you can use: CloudEnteringAlert.PointsInt[i].X + ", " + CloudEnteringAlert.PointsInt[i].Y